# Sort list by multiple variables

Tags: c#

I'd like to sort this list according to the ref and name

What should I type instead of `&&` ?

```
list.Sort((x, y) => x.ref.CompareTo(y.ref) && x.name.CompareTo(y.name));
```

Comment: Maybe `+`?  It depends on what your intent is when comparing the objects.  What specifically makes one instance of `x` "greater than" or "less than" another?

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ:

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(x => x.ref).ThenBy(x => x.name);
```

Comment: Note that while being simple, this creates a new enumeration instead of sorting the existing list in-place, as the OP does.

Answer (score 1):

`CompareTo` yields -1, 0 or 1. A negative number means "first value is less than the second", 0 means "both are equal" and a positive value means "first value is greater than the second". So you could simply sort with

```
list.Sort((x, y) => 2 * x.ref.CompareTo(y.ref) + x.name.CompareTo(y.name));
```

by giving precedence to the sort order of `ref` by multiplying it by 2. Only if the refs are equal, the name has a chance to determine the sign.

If you prefer to first sort by name

```
list.Sort((x, y) => x.ref.CompareTo(y.ref) + 2 * x.name.CompareTo(y.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort first by ref, then by name, using that syntax, it would look like this:

```
list.Sort((x,y)=> {
   var comp = x.ref.CompareTo(y.ref);
   if (comp == 0)
      return x.name.CompareTo(y.name);
   else
      return comp;
});
```

The idea is that you only compare name if ref is equal.